# Why is my DLL detected as suspicious by MSE?

Tags: c++, windows, antivirus

Microsoft Security Essentials continously prompts me to send one of my own DLLs (written in native C++) to Microsoft for further analysis because of (I guess) some kind of suspicious behaviour. I would like to find out why MSE thinks my DLL is suspicious.

The DLL is the client-related code for a 3D Game I am developing in native C++. All it does is using the socket api to connect to a server, process incoming messages from the server, handling mouse and keyboard input (via OIS - Object Oriented Input System), handling some Windows Messages (resize/minimize/quit etc.) and implementing the game's main loop which basically calls functions in my separate renderer.dll (which is fine with MSE). I would say nothing spectacular. I submitted the dll to VirusTotal, 0/48 was the result.

Any ideas? Is there some kind of list of causes for mse thinking it's suspicious? Is there any way to view reasons for further analysis in MSE, like a log file or something?

Comment: They always have a lot of false detections, not only MSE, also others AVs, I had trouble with a lot of them, you can send your DLL to https://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/submission/submit.aspx and tell them to change their code it won't detect your DLL.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can binary search for the suspicious code.  Prepare a version of your DLL with half of the code commented out.  If that version doesn't trigger MSE, then you know the suspicious code is in the half you commented out.  If it does trigger MSE, comment out half of the remaining code.  Iterate until you've narrowed it down.

Identifying the code that triggers the problem may not help you solve the problem directly, but it will allow you to ask a much more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Is suspicious because of:

1. using socket api
2. handling ( hooking ) mouse
3. handling ( hooking ) keyboard
4. handling ( hooking ) messages

and maybe something more not listed above. ( my first spy app used them all )